# Setting Grid width to Auto

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this interface for my ATM WPF app. I used both dock panel and grid. It looks okay but if I maximize the it, it is not 'responsive'. I tried to change grid width to * but it doesn't work. If I set to "Auto", it doesn't look good.

```cs
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">

    <DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel >
            <Button Content="Left Button 1" Height="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Left Button 2" Height="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Left Button 3" Height="100"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Right Button 1" Height="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Right Button 2" Height="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Right Button 3" Height="100"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Grid Margin="10" Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Content="7" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Height="50"/>
            <Button Content="8" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="9" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>

            <Button Content="4" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Height="50"/>
            <Button Content="5" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="6" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

            <Button Content="1" Margin="5" Grid.Row="3" Height="50"/>
            <Button Content="2" Margin="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="3" Margin="5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>

            <Button Content="0" Margin="5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button Content="." Margin="5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Height="50"/>

        </Grid>
    </Button>
    <Button>
        <Grid Margin="10" Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="PIN" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Height="50"/>
            <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="50" />

        </Grid>
    </Button>
</DockPanel>
```

By the way, can I just use Grid for everything here or I have to use combination of dockpanel and grid?

[image]

Comment: Buttons that have StackPanels or Grids with other Buttons as their Content? That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, it looks strange to me too. But when I posted the code at code review, they asked me to post it here.

Comment: I will to do it just with grid then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a set of nested Grids:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Button Content="Left Button 1" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Left Button 2" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Left Button 3" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
        <Button Content="Right Button 1" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Right Button 2" Height="100"/>
        <Button Content="Right Button 3" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="PIN"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <!-- the number keypad -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```